# Where has ViewEngines.DefaultEngine gone an asp.net MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewengine

I was recently trying to get the default view engine in ASP.NET MVC 1.0 and couldn't seem to access the ViewEngines.DefaultEngine property that used to be available in the CTP and Beta versions. Does anyone know what the equivalent in the 1.0 release is?

Comment: Could you explain what you want to do as there might be another way to do it?

Comment: something along the lines of this: http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2008/11/11/another-asp.net-mvc-bug-rendering-views-to-different-output-source.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly then...

To render a partial view, from a jQuery post back, I do the following;

```
return PartialView("Calendar", items);
```

Is this what you were after of did i miss the point of the link you posted?

Comment: not quite... it's to render a view to a string. I have code to render the view to the string but I want to do it with a specific view engine and I want to set the default view engine before I render the view to the string so I can be certain it's the right view engine.